# How to Access the Current Value of the Scale Factor of a Map as a Variable (eg $map_scale) in Print Layouts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, qgis-variable

Does anybody know how to access the current value of the scale factor of a map as a variable (eg $map_scale) in print layouts in QGIS?
I'd love to put the scale factor in my maps...

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Option 1**: Create a text field with the following content:

`1:[%round(map_get(item_variables('Karte'),'map_scale'))%]`

`item_variables('Karte')` points at the item you want to work with. You need to replace `Karte` with the name you gave your map item.

`map_get([...],'map_scale')` grabs the scale of the item you're pointing at. In this case you're returned a number. Since the returned number is a bit off, I added `round(...)`.

**Option 2** (for the lazy... eh, efficient people): Add a scale bar, link it to your map, set its style to `numeric` and you're done.

Comment: Danke Erik [thx]. I'm impressed! #2 works just like a charm out of the box. But about #1: where do I have to put the algo? I tried to put it straight into a `label field`s `Main Properties` window (guessing you meant `label field` instead of `text field` as I actually cannot find a `text field`) and also tried to put the algo by `Insert a Expression` also into the `Main Properties` window of a `label field`. Thx again. I'm looking forward to your repy.

Comment: @Axel to the left there's the rectangle with the T inside of it, that's the one I'm talking about.

Comment: Yes @Erik, we are talking about the same: "text field" == `label field`. After you confirmed me about this I was fiddling around a bit. The problem that I had was that there was no "proper" map id. So I clicked on the actual map in the "Items"-Panel, went to "Item ID" under the "Items Properties"-Panel and assigned a map id (eg "map_xyz"). Now I fed your algo with this map id: `[%round(map_get(item_variables('map_xyz'),'map_scale'))%]` and here we go. Works like a charme. I'm just writing it out loud in case somebody has the same issue here. Thx Erik. Have a nice one!